# javascript multiple message form validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I m using a jquery system in order to validate input in an html form. In the email field I want to display either validate[required] or custom[email] that represent 2 error messages (but not both).
Im not too skilled in Javascript but here's my attempt

```
<form id="formID1" action="report-problem.asp" name="varsForm1" method="post">
<script language="Javascript">...

        function IsEmpty(){
          var class = "";
          if(document.forms['formID1'].email1.value == "")
          {
            class='validate[required]'; 
          }
          else 
          {
               class= 'validate[custom[email]]'; 
          }
          return class;
        }
     </script>

    <td>Email Address</td>
    <td class="input" width="302"><input name="email1" type="text" id="email1" class="IsEmpty();" value="" /></td>....
<input name="" id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Send" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.forms['formID1'].email1.value == "")
  {
   $("#email1").removeClass('validate[custom[email]]');
    class='validate[required]'; 
  }
  else 
  {
       $("#email1").removeClass('validate[required]'); 
       class= 'validate[custom[email]]'; 
  }
  return class;
```

You should remove previous class when you adding new error class in your email field. It should Work :)

Comment: so how would the form look? will it have class="validate[custom[email]]" and then js will replace that or class="Empty();" and js will choose. Because atm I get no reaction from the code

Comment: I have edited my answer take a look. It should work.

Comment: you mean replace the id with email1? i did change that, the problem is elswhere. It just seems not to be processing the script at all. Should i add an OnClick- "run function" command or anything else into the form for it to work

Comment: No Remove your class from input. I am selecting input by the id(email1). Please see basic of jquery.

Comment: Even a simple script does not work at all          
function IsEmpty(){$("#email1").toggleClass('validate[custom[email]]');}